# UITableView tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:) not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use this callback to detect when cells are available to be reused. According to the documentation the signature is:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
       didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, 
       forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

but actually, this doesn't compile with Xcode 7.3 and Swift. I think IndexPath should be NSIndexPath and the _ has to be removed. So I get:

```
@objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
    didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, 
    forRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```

However, this is never called.

The dequeue function is called fine (below) and the table works otherwise:

```
@objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

so that would imply my data-source is working ok.

I am wondering if this is some non-functioning part of the API.

(P.S. I don't recall why the @objc is there, but removing it didn't make any difference).

Comment: The `didEndDisplaying` signature you have there is the Swift 3 version but based on the `cellForRow` signature that you claim is working you are using Swift 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The dequeue function is called fine (below) and the table works
>   otherwise:
>
> ```
> @objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
>     cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
> ```
>
> so that would imply my **data-source** is working ok.

Note that [tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview) refers to `UITableViewDelegate`, not for `UITableViewDataSource`. I suggest to check that your class also *does* conforms to `UITableViewDelegate`.

Also, using Xcode 7.3 means you are writing Swift 2.x, it should be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //...
}
```

In Swift 3, it should be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // ...
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: OK - that was it. I was confused between the data-source and the delegate proper. In the view controller and with the correct signature it works OK. And thanks for the Swift 3 info. I had been ignoring it a bit.